# JavaScript loop and jQuery Append too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Attempting to append via jQuery to a div, looping over a simple 25 index array.

Everything appends, however the append is done 25 times, meaning I get 625 results when I only needed 25.

The array looks like this but up to data25:

```
["data", "data2", "data3"]
```

My code to append looks like this

```
$.each(stores, function(index, value) {
     $('.display-nearest-stores').append(value); 
     console.log(value)
});
```

Comment: are you sure that this is what `stores` contains before the loop? maybe try `console.log()` it before going in the loop. or maybe there's some other loop or event handler wrapping it..

Comment: How and where is `stores` created? Where is the call to `$.each` run?

Comment: can u post all your code once

Comment: Within the console.log I only get 25 stores returned and not 625, but when I jQuery append I  get too many

Comment: try `console.log(stores.length)` if there is 25 elements

Comment: Maybe you have 25 divs? Do you generate any html dynamically?

Comment: Have you tried: for(i in stores) $('.display-nearest-stores').append(stores[i]);

Comment: Can you give us a relevant part from your html?

Comment: My guess is that you have 25 elements of `$('.display-nearest-stores')`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="jsondata"> 
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data=["data", "data2", "data3"];
  var sizeofdata=$(data).size();
  for(i=0;i<sizeofdata;i++)
 {
 $('#jsondata').append(data[i]+'<br>');
 } 
});
```

this may help you or https://jsfiddle.net/susanadhikary/knx0awtu/